# Installing Pillow for Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am fairly new to Python and trying to install the Pillow package on Windows 7. I downloaded and ran the MS Windows installer Pillow-2.2.1.win-amd64-py3.3.exe from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.2.1#downloads). It appeared to install fine. If I run the simple line of code:

```
from PIL import Image
```

directly from the Python interpreter, it runs fine. A help() on PIL gives me the package contents.

But when I try to run the same line of code from within a script, I get an `ImportError: No module named PIL`. What am I missing?

(Note that I've been able to `import sys` and `import MySQLdb` from within scripts just fine.)

---

**Resolved**: sure, enough, I'm running Python 2.7 when I run scripts. (I think I vaguely recall having to install an older version so I could interface with MySQL.) Thank you all for pointing out that I should check the version being used.

Comment: Can you paste the traceback?

Comment: check that your script uses the same python executable where you've installed Pillow e.g., add at the top of the Python script: `#!python3.3` if you have one one python3.3 installation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For third-party modules for Windows, my go-to resource is Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). You can find the latest version of Pillow [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow). Make sure you're working with the python.org version of Python.

As far as your specific error, it's hard to tell exactly without a traceback, but make sure your script is calling the correct version of Python. If you have also installed Python 2.7, for example, your script may be calling that instead of 3.3.

Comment: Thanks, yep. The script is calling Python 2.7, not 3.3.

Comment: I needed Pillow 2.3.2, doesn't seem to be there :(

Comment: @Zhianc Gohlke's site isn't an archive. You can get previous versions from PyPI like [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.3.2#downloads). You'll have to build from source, though.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases I'm simply printing the `sys.path` at the beginning of the script in trouble and comparing it with the one from the working python interpreter. In most cases I was running the script with a different python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks, yep. That's exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I was referring to wrong pip folder.
Changed virtual environment in pycharm to point to right pip folder to solve this issue

```
import sys
print ( sys.path )
```