# How to install Pillow on Python 3.6.4 (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am looking to do some coding on my laptop, practicing and trying to teach my self new things that I can add when I came across adding pictures. This requires Pillow, but I have no idea on where to start to download it. 
Please can someone help by telling me how to download and install Pillow on Windows?

Comment: Use `pip` to install it. Run the following against your command line:  `python3 -m pip install Pillow`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Pillow for Python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596204/installing-pillow-for-python-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Now for python version 3.X you need to specify

```
> pip3 install pillow
```

pil is now pillow